# How can one populate a vector with all possible string combinations of n vector length in the C++ programming language

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector of 100 strings and another empty vector and I'm trying to fill the empty vector with every possible combination of n strings from the group of 100. (n = 1, 2, 3,...)

If n =1 then you get every unique vector composed of 1 string (or all 100 strings as vectors)

If n =2 then you get every unique vector composed of 2 strings(or 100^2 variations)

C++ is not my native language.

I have some attempts so far, and what I'd do in Zou_script (proprietary in-house) would be to assign each string a number and then permute through all possible combinations of those numbers, and then reference individual strings through Vector[] to create the vectors.

This seems slow and has a lack of elegance, holding the string bank in memory could be bad if the string bank was much bigger.

I have used std::next_permutation but I'm having trouble extending it elegantly to sorting vectors composed of strings.

How can one populate a vector with all possible string combinations of n vector length in the C++ programming language? <- Question.

Might anyone be of any assistance? If you're unsure, or intimidated by the question it's OK to go to the next one.

Update

I have managed to replicate the technique in C++ but next_permutation is significantly slower because it does not understand it does not need to calculate the entire permutation vector, only up to n amount.

Any way to manipulate next_permutation to only calculate x elements of a vector permutation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: I am guessing that *loops* would be required to generate every *permutation* or *combination*.  Hint:  Search the internet for "C++ permutation example" or "C++ generate combination example".

Comment: Are you sure you want to populate a vector with *every* combination out of a set of 100 entries? This will result in a vector of about 1e+158 entries, which will rarely fit into memory of a usual machine, right?

Comment: Stephan Lechner this is very true, if the vectors were held simultaneously, but the vector could hold the strings (and be written to a file, a hard drive much larger than the memory) and then move forward in the algorithm and the data can be parsed later.

However this isn't the sole purpose and the vector needs to be manipulated as well, so it isn't as easy as printing the combination to the file.

Comment: @prof_dunwem: 1e+158 is *far* too large to store on any hard drive. No hard drive this large has ever or will ever be built. To put this in perspective, 1e+158 *dwarfs* the number of atoms in the milky way galaxy.

Comment: I am having a good laugh about the absurdity (not at anyone) but I see that there has been some misunderstanding. This event would only occur if n was chosen to be comparable to the string bank size. If I chose n to be 1, then I would get a list of 100 vectors composed of 1 string.

Comment: @JerryCoffin how do I add a point to your comment, I keep laughing when I read it.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with simply iterating. Also, I'm not clear on the upper bounds. And what about sorting? If you want some arbitrary i'th permutation based on sort, then that seems quickly computable by sorting the initial vector, then taking indexes with i % 100 (although you will need a math library to store arbitrarily large numbers). You ask a lot of questions and give no criteria for judging an answer.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I found an amazing implementation here for what I do: 

https://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html

With this you can make much more efficient permutation lists in which to match to the elements! 

I think it is slower to calculate modulus and then back to index than to sort the indexes with math. (if I understand correct)

I have since solved this problem with next::permutation (generic function for considering y elements of a pool of x elements - then sorting and deleting duplicates in a vector. This is much slower than this implementation linked.

Comment: I've never met anyone speaking C++ as their "native language"

Comment: I am glad that my humor is not lost on you Phuc.

Comment: Did I do something wrong? I seem to have multiple people who don't appreciate the question. I did do some preliminary searching but I was not using the proper terminology so I was not getting useful results. After narrowing my terminology after being educated on permutations in C++ I am able to find much more useful tutorials. However, instructive questions like this only serve to help people find what they are looking for, if there is anyone who thought like me and searched this topic out they would find this question the way I thought to word it. Anyways I hope that you are all well.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question but I will do the best that I can to give an answer. This is in fact a well researched and often asked question in C/C++.

"How to consider permutations of a group of N elements, r at a time?"

There are many ways to tackle the problem. One such way is to generate a vector of integers with which to map to a vector of your elements.

Using std::next_permutation you can generate a list of numbers (permutations of the integer vector) and truncate to the amount of items you are considering. This list can then be sorted using vector tools, duplicates removed. This will give you a list of all unique permutations of N integers, r at a time, for mapping to your element vector.

Then it can be as easy as calling the r numbers from your permutation integer list and using them in your element list index to generate the permutations of your elements.

```
for (int k = 0; k < linecount_of_integer_permutation_list; k++)
{

     // insert code for calling up integer permutation list line
     // and assigning that permutation to vector

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
{
file <<  element[intvec[r]]; // can put whatever delimiters you want/need
}
file << std::endl;
intvec.clear();
// remember to clear vectors, or other flags depending on what you need
}
```

This is cumbersome and very slow.

https://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html

Has some very good ideas on how to handle this issue faster. The above will work for small sets, however the jump from small to absolutely unmanageable is very quick in permutations.

Thank you for all your help. It is actually an interesting question but apparently it isnt needed for many people's applications in programming.